# elk stack error "unable to fetch mapping do you have indices matching the pattern"

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, collectd, kibana, elk

i am trying to setup ELK stack with collectd on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (so pretty much latest version of stack available)
kibana is behind nginx proxy (followed this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04)

and all looking good up until going to kibana dashboard

```
Index Patterns 

Warning No default index pattern. You must select or create one to continue.

unable to fetch mapping do you have indices matching the pattern
```

ELK stack is on one server so everything on localhost

Below are commands i ran to check my configurations

```
:~# curl 127.0.0.1:9200`
{
  "name" : "Flex",
  "cluster_name" : "elk-00",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.3",
    "build_hash" : "218bdf10790eef486ff2c41a3df5cfa32dadcfde",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-05-17T15:40:04Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"


:~# service logstash configtest
Configuration OK
```

**My question, very specific**

**1. How do i create defualt index file?**

**2. What is path of this default index file or located? also i hear about .kibana, where is this file .kibana located?**

**3. Why wasn't this index file automatically created for me? What do i do to make sure it automatically works without manually doing anything else?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently this error occurs because elasticsearch has no data in yet
one has to load data into it

followed this guide to load data into elasticsearch and everything starts to work like a charm!

[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/getting-started.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20201021124956/https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/getting-started.html) (Link via archive.org)

Comment: In my case there was no default index. just set default index and evey thing start working again